# Is magnetic susceptibility per unit volume, or per unit mass?

Tags: electromagnetism

maybe very silly question :(

In Magnetism:

\begin{equation}
\ B=H+4\pi M (SI)
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\ B=\mu(H+M) (CGS)
\end{equation}

in these formulas M is Volume Magnetisation

\begin{equation}
\ M=d \mu/dV
\end{equation}

or

\begin{equation}
\ M=d \mu/dm
\end{equation}

Answer (score 1):

$M$ is the dipole moment per unit volume (see [Wikipedia](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetization) for discussion).  If you carefully define what the variables in your question are, it will be easier for us to tell you what's correct:

If by $\mu$ in the second set of equations, you mean "magnetic moment is some sufficiently small region $V$", than $M=\frac{d\mu}{dV}$ makes sense.

On the other hand, if by $\mu$ you mean the magnetic permeability (as you do in the first set of equations), the only relevant expression I can think of is $(\mu/\mu_0-1)=\frac{dM}{dH}$, where the quantity on the right-hand side is the [volume magnetic susceptibility](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_susceptibility).

(I also don't think I know what you mean by lowercase $m$, sorry.)